# sql integration between two databases Sage300 and ToolHound

Tags: sql

So I have these two databases Sage300 and Toolhound How should i arrange the API's to be live synce with SQL now Toolhound offers a API that contains DTO's Sage is the pain we will have to use Crystal reporting to finalize the communication. Just need assistance with the SQL pointing.

NA This is a new concept to try to implement

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked into using database convergence software?

Comment: For this kind of consideration, use the comments section, not the answer, which is supposed to provide a direct solution